# spx for moving values to new table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create one spx which based upon my ID which is 1009 will move 9 columns data to new table:

The old table has 9 columns:

```
CD_Train
CD_Date
CD_Score
Notes_Train
Notes_Date
Notes_Score
Ann_Train
Ann_Date
Ann_Score 
userid - common in both tables
ID - 1009 - only exists in this table
```

and my new table has:

```
TrainingID, 
TrainingType,
Score,
Date,
Status,
userid
```

TrainingType will have 3 values: Notes, CD, Ann 
and other fields like score will get data from notes_score and so on 
and date will get data from notes_date,cd_date depending upon in which column cd training went

status will get value from Notes_Train, cd_train and so on

based upon this, I am lost how should I do it

I tried querying one sql of users table and tried to do the join but I am losing the ground how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

No idea yet, how to fill your column `trainingId` but the rest can be done by applying some `UNION ALL`  clauses:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (trainingType,Date,Score,Status,userid)
Select 'CD' , CD_date, CD_score, CD_Train, userid FROM  tbl1 where CD_date>0
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Notes', Notes_Date, Notes_Score, Notes_Train, userid FROM tbl1 where Notes_date>0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ann', Ann_Date, Ann_Score, ANN_Train, userid 
FROM tbl1 where Ann_date>0
```

I don't know as yet whether all columns are filled in each row. That is the reason for the where clauses which should filter out only those rows with relevant data in the three selected columns.

Comment: trainingid is not required and i want to copy all records even empty